# How can I dynamically change priority of applications in foreground

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a script that loops every 15 seconds or so (as to not unnecessarily consume processing work) and gets a list of all applications running in the *foreground* or *fullscreen window*, loops through the object list of those processes and sets their priority to **High** while looping through all other processes that are in the *background* and sets their priority to **Below Normal**.

This script was originally intended to do this on one specific game, Rimworld. Which is single threaded, and so I made a script that set the affinity of the game exclusively to the first 2 threads from core 1 with the rest of the system on the remaining 3 cores and 6 threads (4 core, 8 thread processor) and incorporated the aforementioned priority setting as part of the script. However, I decided I wanted to expand this to other games some of which do take advantage of multiple threads and leave out the affinity settings all together and just focus on priority assignment. Unfortunately I was unable to find a good post or page that detailed how I can use the process list of powershell to filter down to only foreground or fullscreen windows. Seemingly only a WMI command which, when I tried to use as a variable in powershell returns an error saying **the format is not correct** when trying to use the WMI Object variable as the list for the processes to make changes on.

So my question is can I do what I am trying to achieve exclusively with PowerShells process list or is there a way to translate the WMI object variable into a format that will be compatible with the Powershell process command. Thanks :)

**Code (Please ignore the commented out section about HT on and off):**

```
#Ensures the script runs as an administrator
If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator))
{
    # Relaunch as an elevated process:
    Start-Process powershell.exe "-File",('"{0}"' -f $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) -Verb RunAs
    exit
}

#This scripts checks to see if Rimworld is open, if it is open it will set Rimworld exclusive access over the first
#2 cores (4 Threads with hyperthreading enabled), set its priority, IO priority and page priority to high.

Get-CimInstance -ClassName 'Win32_Processor' | Select-Object -Property 'Name','NumberOfCores','NumberOfLogicalProcessors' | Write-Host
$Cores = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName 'Win32_Processor' | Select-Object -Property 'NumberOfCores')
$LogicalCores = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName 'Win32_Processor' | Select-Object -Property 'NumberOfLogicalProcessors')
<# if ($Cores -Ne $LogicalCores){
    Write-Host "Since HyperThreading affects single threaded performance, and Rimworld is a single-threaded application,
     it is recommended you disable hyperthreading in the BIOS
    for the best performance in Rimworld."
    Write-Host "Would you like to do that now?"
    $Input = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please type 1 for Yes or 2 for No.'
    Switch ($Input)
    {
        1 {
            Write-Host "In BIOS enter, CPU > Advanced, Hyper-Threading (Intel) OR SMT (AMD)."
            Write-Host "Set as Disabled, Save and exit BIOS."
            shutdown -r -t 15 -fw -c "Restarting to Firmware"}
    }
        2 {
            Write-Host "Okay"
        }

}
#>
Do {
    $IsRimworldActive = (Get-Process -Name "*Rimworld*")
    $IsRimworldActive
    if ($IsRimworldActive.ProcessName -contains "RimWorldWin64")
    {
        $Rimworld = (Get-Process -Name "*Rimworld*" | Select-Object ProcessorAffinity)
        $Rimworld.ProcessorAffinity = 3
        $Rimworld = (Get-Process -Name "RimWorldWin64")
        $Rimworld.PriorityBoostEnabled = 'True'
        $Rimworld.PriorityClass = "RealTime"
        $NotRimworld = ((Get-Process -Name "*") -NotMatch "RimWorld" | Select-Object ProcessorAffinity)
        $NotRimworld | ForEach-Object { $_.ProcessorAffinity = 252 }
        $NotRimworld = ((Get-Process -Name "*") -NotMatch "RimWorld")
        $NotRimworld | ForEach-Object {
            $_.PriorityBoostEnabled = 'False'
            $_.PriorityClass = "Idle"
        }
        $Rimworld
        $NotRimworld
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
    }
    else
    {
        $NotRimworld = ((Get-Process -Name "*") -NotMatch "RimWorld" | Select-Object ProcessorAffinity)
        $NotRimworld | ForEach-Object { $_.ProcessorAffinity = 255 }
        $NotRimworld = ((Get-Process -Name "*") -NotMatch "RimWorld")
        $NotRimworld | ForEach-Object {
            $_.PriorityBoostEnabled = 'True'
            $_.PriorityClass = "Normal"
        }
        $NotRimworld
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
    }} While ($IsRimworldActive = (Get-Process -Name "*Rimworld*"), ($IsRimworldActive.ProcessName -contains "RimWorldWin64"))
```

Comment: ` Get-WmiObject Win32_process -filter 'name = "ProcessName"' | foreach-object { $_.SetPriority(<Priorit Level>) }` where `<Priority Level>` is 256 for Realtime,128 for High, 32768 for Above normal, 32 for Normal, 16384 for Below normal, and 64 for Low. https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/89548-set-cpu-process-priority-applications-windows-10-a.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WMI is legacy and is dropped in PowerShell 7. Please consider shifting to CIM instead, using using Get-CimInstance, that supports (almost) the same structure...

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter 'name = "Explorer.exe"' | 
  select Name,Priority
```

The only difference is how methods are used...

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter 'name = "Explorer.exe"' | 
  Invoke-CimMethod -Name SetPriority -Arguments @{Priority=16384}
```

For the viable arguments, look up the SetPriority method
[MS Docs - SetPriority method of the Win32_Process class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/setpriority-method-in-class-win32-process#parameters)